# How to perfom horizontal rank filtering for edge detection?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, extract, edge-detection

I do some recognizing of plate numbers, but I'm stuck when doing extraction on them. I read references that state I have to perform horizontal rank filtering but I don't know how to do it.

Code:

```
a = imread('Izy.jpg');
b = imresize(a,0.5);
c = rgb2gray(b);
Py = [ -1,0,1; -1,0,1 ; -1,0,1];        
Gp = conv2(c,Py);
Gpx = edge(Gp,'prewitt');
cl = bwareaopen(Gpx,10);
imshow(cl)
```

[image: Izy.jpg]

[image: output image and i want get the red rectangled that i mark then crop it]

I've read references that say we have to use vertical edge prewitt; I'm using horizontal rank filtering to extract the plate number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a code to work for this particular image, but not a general one. Here we have the input image.

[image: Original Image]

```
a = imread('Izy.jpg');
b = imresize(a,0.5);
c = rgb2gray(b);
```

The code until here reads the image into variable `a`, scales it down to half the size (stored in `b`) and then converts it from a 3 channel image to grayscale (stored in `c`). I would suggest to use Canny edge detector over Prewitt detector as follows:

```
Gpx = edge(c,'canny');
L = bwlabel(Gpx,8);
```

[image: Edge Detected Image]

- The edge detected binary image (stored in `Gpx`) will have several foreground images or regions. A region is a collection of pixels, which each of the member pixels connected to at least 1 of it's 8 neighboring pixels. These regions be labeled with the use of `bwlabel()` and stored in `L`.
- Using `regionprops('properties','properties',..)`, we get a structure with different properties of the regions present in the image.

Here, `area` and `eccentricity` properties are calculated for the regions. `eccentricity` values helps us identify is a region is a circular or linear. For circle, the value is `0` and for a line, the value is `1`

```
imgstat = regionprops(L,'Area','Eccentricity');
area = [imgstat.Area];
ecc = [imgstat.Eccentricity];
```

Since we have 129 (`size(imgstat)`) regions in the image, each region will have some area and eccentricity values. Use trial and error to identify the required values for `area` and `eccentricity` properties.

Apply the approximate property values to get the boundary of the license plate, and store the region index in `label`. `logical_result` extracts and stores the required region from the labeled image.

```
label = find((area > 150) & (ecc < 0.95) & (ecc > 0.9));
logical_result = ismember(L,label);
figure;imshow(logical_result)
```

The image stored in `logical_result`

[image: Extracted regions]

Now, calculate the boundary values from`logical_result`. These values are recovered as indices and so, we have to convert them into subscripts using `ind2sub()`. From the boundary values we can extract the region of interest from the original image

```
[row, col] = ind2sub([size(c,1), size(c,2)],find(logical_result == 1));
result = c(min(row):max(row),min(col):max(col));
imshow(result);
```

This gives the following result:

[image: Output Obtained]

Comment: sorry for asking again, thanks to you ,i know how the codes work but if i use another image , the result is unidentify and i use trial and error but no result. do you any suggestion to extract another plate number, ? and there are so many regionprops , when the best time we use like area,eccentricity,boundingbox,etc. Thanks b4

Comment: I have never tried to create a generalized code for this. That code was specifically written for the input image you posted. 

I'd suggest you to look for some research papers on license place extraction from images and read through the algorithms used there.

`regionprops` properties are used based on the requirements of the user. We can't really suggest the best times to use the properties.Sometimes, you may need the perimeter, or orientation of the image instead of area or eccentricity.